# Neo4J - JPA - Doesn't return the relationship entity

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-jpa, cypher

I have a following data model in Neo4J graph database.

```
(Employee)--[:REPORTS_TO]-->(Employee) // n-to-1 relation
(Employee)--[:HAS_SKILL]--(Skill) // 1-to-n relation
```

My JPA entity classes:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Employee {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;

    @Relationship(type = "REPORTS_TO", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private Employee manager;

    @Relationship(type = "HAS_SKILL", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private Set<Skill> skills; //Can have multiple skills
}
```

and

```
@NodeEntity
public class Skill {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
}
```

I want to search Employee who has skill named `X` (for e.g.).
So in my Java Application I wrote JPA method with named query as follows:

```
@Query("match (e:Employee)-[:HAS_SKILL]->(s:Skill{name:$0}) return e")
List<Employee> findBySkill(String skill);
```

The query works perfectly and returns the employees who has the desired skill.
But when I print the Objects the Relationship entities of the Employee (`manager` and `skills`) are `null`.

Then I tried the below query:

```
match (e:Employee)-[:HAS_SKILL]->(s:Skill{name:$0}) match (e)-[r]->(m) return e,r,m
```

Now this query returned all the entities which were null in the previous one but also listed additional Employee node which doesn't match the skill but it was a manager node of an employee who has the desired skill.

So how can I get all employees which has skill X and the result should contain the relationship entities as well (meaning relationship entities not null)?

Comment: Did you set a specific load depth in your session ? https://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/reference/#reference:session:loading-entities:load-depth. Maybe see here too https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH-685

Comment: The links which you provided looks like to increase the depth while querying with properties. In fact, when I query any nodes with property, it works fine. 
The problem is when querying with relation - Again the result which I get is good but it doesn't return the dependent nodes

Comment: I am not competent on neo4j. But your problem is very close to what I have already seen with JPA, on lazy loading relationships and late access (out of session) to linked entities. While browsing the neo4J doc, the "load depth" parameter seems to addressed this kind of issue. The doc says that load depth si set to 0 on find methods, while you obviously need a deeper load of linked entities.
Just my 2 cents. Sorry, I can't offer a better help.